# Highlight whole row on hover

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a javaScript function that loops through a variable number of iterations and spits HTML to the DOM / Webpage. Thus after the loop it fills the following div:

```
  <div class="energyRowContainer" id="energyRowContainer">

  </div>
```

like so...

```
<div class="energyRowContainer" id="energyRowContainer">

<div id="energyRow0" class="energyRow">
<div class="energyTypeHead"> 1.2.2012 </div><div class="energyUnitMWH"> 93 </div><div class="energyUnitT"> 174 </div><div class="energyUnitM3_1"> 6594 </div><div class="energyUnitM3_2"> 116 </div><div class="energyUnitM3_3"> 34162 </div><div class="energyUnitM3_4"> 2625 </div><div class="energyUnitM3_5"> 17886 </div> <div class="energyUnitM3_6"> 21 </div>
</div>

<div id="energyRow1" class="energyRow">
<div class="energyTypeHead"> 1.2.2012 </div><div class="energyUnitMWH"> 93 </div><div class="energyUnitT"> 174 </div><div class="energyUnitM3_1"> 6594 </div><div class="energyUnitM3_2"> 116 </div><div class="energyUnitM3_3"> 34162 </div><div class="energyUnitM3_4"> 2625 </div><div class="energyUnitM3_5"> 17886 </div> <div class="energyUnitM3_6"> 21 </div>
</div>

<div>
```

now I'd like to use Jquery or CSS to change the background color of the whole row (class="energyRow") however simply creating a energyRow:hover doesn't work as I'm hovering over the child divs... I've thought about using like this but I"m getting nowhere... any ideas anyone?

```
$('#energyRowContainer > .energyRow, ').hover(function() {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('name_of_a_hover_class');
});
```

Comment: nothing seems to work here... something just isn't right? Hmm...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your issue was that you were adding the elements to the DOM dynamically but not using event delegation binding methods like `.delegate()`. This can be done with CSS though (which will be good for performance, although adding a class to an element via JS doesn't create much more overhead):

```
#energyRowContainer .energyRow:hover {
    background : yellow;
}
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zNWGL/

Also, you were so close, all you needed to do was remove the `.parent()` from your selection. Here is a demo of your code sans the `.parent()`: http://jsfiddle.net/zNWGL/1/

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
$('#energyRowContainer').find('.energyRow').hover(function() {
    $(this).parent().addClass('name_of_a_hover_class'); // On hover
}, function() {
    $(this).parent().removeClass('name_of_a_hover_class'); // On not hover
});
```

Don't forget to add this after you div's or in your ready event.

Answer (score 0):

The issue in your code is that you are using `$(this).parent()` which is selecting the parent of the element you hovered on and toggling the class on it.

You just have to use `$(this)`, it will point to the container you hovered on and toggle class on it.

Also since the elements are added dynamically you should use `delegate` on `on`(added in jQuery 1.7)

Using `delegate`:

```
$('#energyRowContainer').delegate('.energyRow', 'hover', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('name_of_a_hover_class');
});
```

Using `on`:

```
$('#energyRowContainer').on('hover', '.energyRow', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('name_of_a_hover_class');
});
```

However you can achieve this behavior through pure css like this.

```
.energyRow:hover {
    background : whateverColor;
}
```

- `.delegate()` reference - http://api.jquery.com/delegate/
- `.on()` reference - http://api.jquery.com/on/